# Password doesn't work if type too fast

Tags: command-line, password

So basically when I type my user password I HAVE to type it pretty slow for it to register, e.g. ~sudo, it says "Sorry, try again" but when i type it slowly it accepts the password.

I think this is a feature against brute force attacks but can I turn it off somehow?

Using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS .

Thanks.

Comment: You mention your release (22.04) but not if you're asking about a Destkop install (thus logging in via `gdm3`) or Server install (thus logging in via text terminal).

Comment: Thanks for replying, sorry but I'm not sure what you meant, I'm pretty new to linux, fresh installed the iso a few days ago via USB stick. Anything that wants me to enter my password tells me to try again if i enter it too fast, a typo isn't a possibility I just enter it too fast.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but that's only partial details; as we don't know if you're asking about Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop??  or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server?? or another *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04. The login procedures differ & you've not specified which password entry procedure you're asking about. I am aware some USB keyboards can't cope with multi-keystrokes (ie. if you press R but have started pressing T being the next character in a password but haven't released the R key; some keyboard correctly understand this, others cannot due to electronics being used - but you gave no specifics)

Comment: Is this happening only during password entry? What happens if you type _the same_ password into a text editor running on the same system?

Comment: @guiverc it's not ghosting either, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop for regular use, Jammy Jellyfish. When I turn on my computer and it asks me for my user login password or when entering the password after doing $sudo in terminal or $snap.

Comment: @FedKad yup only when entering the password, on a text editor nothing happens, i type my password in like a millisecond.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help guys, i changed my password to something simpler through ~~sudo passwd (username)~~ and now i can type it as fast as i want to!

Answer (score 0):

SOmetimes, when I type faster than my fingers are willing to tolerate, I get the thing that happened with the first word of this sentence. I was going to go back and correct, it, but I then thought, no, this is a perfect example.

Or perhaps it's my keyboard. I should take a toothbrush to it and see.

Any chance that's what's happening with you?

Comment: I promise I'm typing it correctly, i just switched from WIndows to LInux and it's the same password i used for my log in for like 6 years, so a typo of some sorts isn't a problem. I swear I've read about the same issue somewhere but I cannot find the thread if my life depended on it.